# Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "test" to BN.js instance

Tags: web3js, truffle

I'm trying to deploy the contract which does not use number to bignumber conversion itself. But I'm getting the following error about the code from node_modules:

```
Error: Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "test" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "test"
at toBN (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-utils\src\utils.js:64:1)
at Method.hexToNumber [as outputFormatter] (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-utils\src\utils.js:234:1)
at Method.formatOutput (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js:163:1)
at sendTxCallback (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js:473:1)
at C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:147:1
at C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\wrapper.js:112:1
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\inbpack:\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:96:1)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-rack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-requestode_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:1)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\giusha9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:28dules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:47)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Truffle v5.1.15 (core: 5.1.15)
Node v10.16.0
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "authcoin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Solidity Smart Contracts for Authcoin",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "truffle compile",
    "build": "truffle build",
    "deploy": "truffle deploy",
    "postinstall": "truffle install",
    "console": "truffle console",
    "testrpc": "testrpc --gasLimit 60000000",
    "testrpc:coverage": "node_modules/.bin/testrpc-sc --port 8555",
    "truffle-test": "truffle test",
    "test": "run-p --aggregate-output --race testrpc truffle-test",
    "solidity-coverage": "node_modules/.bin/solidity-coverage",
    "coverage": "run-p --aggregate-output --race testrpc:coverage solidity-coverage",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/solium --dir ./contracts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "ethereumjs-testrpc": "^6.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.2.7",
    "solium": "^0.5.5",
    "ethereumjs-util": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "truffle": "5.0.14"
  }
}
```

Truffle version returns the following:

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.1.15 (core: 5.1.15)
Solidity - 0.4.18 (solc-js)
Node v10.16.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:
This is constructor and the function used in constructor:

```
function AuthCoin() {
        registerSignatureVerifier(new DummyVerifier(), bytes32("test"));
    }


function registerSignatureVerifier(SignatureVerifier signatureVerifier, bytes32 eirType) onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
        if (address(signatureVerifiers[eirType]) == address(0)) {
            verifierIdList.push(eirType);
        }
        signatureVerifiers[eirType] = signatureVerifier;
        LogNewSignatureVerifier(signatureVerifier, eirType);
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT:

this is deployment code:

```
var AuthCoinContract = artifacts.require("./AuthCoin.sol");
var BytesUtils = artifacts.require("./utils/BytesUtils.sol");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(BytesUtils);
  deployer.link(BytesUtils, AuthCoinContract);
  deployer.deploy(AuthCoinContract);
};
```

Comment: "contract which does not use number to bignumber conversion itself" - no contract does that. In contract code, there are only numbers (`uint` variables). Please share the relevant part of your contract code (i.e., the constructor), and the relevant part of your deployment code.

Comment: Are you sure that Truffle is configured to use solc 0.4.18?

Comment: Also, where is your deployment code? The error described in your question comes from there, not from the contract.

Comment: I have specified solc version for this prohect in truffle-config.js 
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.4.18",
      settings: {
        evmVersion: "constantinople"
      }
    },
  }

Comment: Why do you link `AuthCoinContract`? Is that a library? Also, please add some printout before and after every line in your deployment script, in order to reveal which line throws the given error.

Comment: And if the problem is in `BytesUtils` (which could very well be the case), then please post the relevant code of that one as well. Your question is missing a lot of information which you could easily obtain using some minimal debugging effort. Please do this effort.

Comment: I debugged the transactions and it was actually ByteUtils which had the problem. Unfortunately I'm new to solidity and couldn't print the text in migration file. https://codepaste.ml/bfd33de8/
this is the ByteUtils file. AuthcoinContract is the main contract which I'm trying to deploy, it is not a library. Thanks